# How do I charge each user of my decentralized application a fee?

Tags: dapps, payments

I'm just learning how to build a decentralized application, and I have one question. Suppose I want to charge each user a fee of 1 ETH to use the application. If they don't pay, they don't get to use my app.

How would I charge the user and enforce that this fee has been paid before they are allowed to use my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to @Medici's answer, you can create a modifier for all your functions such that only payed users can call them.

```js
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract PayedService {

    mapping (address => bool) public isCustomer;

    modifier onlyCustomer(){
        require(isCustomer[msg.sender]);
        _;
    }

    function becomeCustomer() payable external {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        isCustomer[msg.sender] = true;
    }
    
    function doSomething() public onlyCustomer{
        // some function
    }

}
```

In this pattern, users will have to pay 1 ETH to become a customer and only then interact with other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the space! In order to require a certain amount is paid, you can use the `payable` function modifier and add a require statement at the beginning of your the function which executes the service in question that says if `require(msg.value == 1 ether)`.

In case this isn't clear I'll give a simple example through a counter function.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Counter {

    uint256 public val;

    function increaseByOne() payable external {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);

        val++;
    }
}
```

In the function `increaseByOne`, if the `msg.value` is not 1 ether, the function will revert (i.e. service will not be rendered).